# images are not displaying in php

Tags: php

I have two project folders in my server:

```
    Icare_image
    imagedental
```

Now I am displaying `icare_image/images/photos` these images in `imagedental/demo3/service.php`

Images are not displaying with the code below, and I am wondering if you can spot what the issue is?

```
<div class="entry-thumb">
    <a href="viewservice.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_photo'];?>">
    <?php echo'<img src="fediclix/icare_image/images/photos'.$row["photo"].'"/>'; ?>
        <div class="blog-overlay"><span class="image-overlay-inside"></span></div></a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this

```
   <?php echo'<img src="../../icare_image/images/photos'.$row["photo"].'"/>'; ?>
```